# is there a user accessible list of col_types in readr (not in the documentation)?

Tags: r, readr

These are listed in the documentation for `readr::cols()` but are the also available as an exported object anywhere?

Comment: What format do you need them in? If you just want them listed as a character vector then perhaps something like `grep('^col_', ls(envir = asNamespace('readr')), value = TRUE)`? This is actually similar to the method that readr itself uses to find whether a type has a defined `col_[type]` function.

Comment: Thanks Allan, Yeah a character vector is good thanks,  I was looking to use it for a validation check.

Answer (score 0):

I got the names of the valid readr column type as a character vector using [Allan Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron)'s comment above.

```r
grep('^col_', ls(envir = asNamespace('readr')), value = TRUE)

> 'col_character''col_concise''col_date''col_datetime''col_double''col_factor''col_guess''col_integer''col_logical''col_number''col_skip''col_spec''col_spec_melt''col_spec_standardise''col_time''col_to_short'
```